# Loading images from parse in uiscrollview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pffile

I want to retrieve images from a PFFile, which contains multiple images, and put them in one scrollview. So far, I have tried the following, but this returns an error "Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread."

```
    let scrView = UIScrollView()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Pictures")
    query.whereKey("uploader", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for post in posts!{
                self.imageFiles.append(post["imageFile"]as! PFFile)
                self.imageText.append(post["imageText"]as! String)
            }


    for var i = 0; i < self.pictNumber; ++i {
        var userImageFile = self.imageFiles[i]
        println(userImageFile)
        var imgFileData = userImageFile.getData()
        var image = UIImage(data: imgFileData!)
        var tempImageView = UIImageView (image: image)
        tempImageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(width*i), 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        scrView.addSubview(tempImageView)


        }
```

I have also tried the following, but it skips the part where it extracts images from PFFile and adds the images to the scrollview.

```
    let scrView = UIScrollView()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Pictures")
    query.whereKey("uploader", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for post in posts!{
                self.imageFiles.append(post["imageFile"]as! PFFile)
                self.imageText.append(post["imageText"]as! String)
            }


    for var i = 0; i < self.pictNumber; ++i {
        var userImageFile = self.imageFiles[i]
        println(userImageFile)

        //Extracting pictures from PFFile
        self.imageFiles[i].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if imageData != nil {
                var image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                var tempImageView = UIImageView (image: image)
                tempImageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(width*i), 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
                scrView.addSubview(tempImageView)
                println(i)

            }else {
                println(error)
            }}



        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock() instead of userImageFile.getData()

userImageFile.getData gets the file in the main thread which can potentially freeze your UI if the file is large or you have a slow internet connection

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error:

> Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main
>   thread.

Which means you have to do that task into main thread and you can do it by using this code :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //add your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the same error continues to occur.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  var imgFileData = userImageFile.getData()

Comment: I put  "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                                                            

        for var i = 0; i < self.pictNumber; ++i {" but the same error still occurs